# I am not alive, but I grow; I don't have lungs, but I need air; I don't have a mouth, but I need water to live. What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I am not alive, but I grow; I don't have lungs, but I need air; I don't have a mouth, but I need water to live. What am I?

> Focus on the water aspect - and don't fall into doubt.

Comment: *"I need water to live"* -- "Live" seems deceptive, since you're not alive. Why not just "I need water"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be this:

> a wave

> It is made of water, grows over time and it needs air to form. And it doesn't live.

Comment: Why does it need air to form?

Comment: rot13(Jvaq pbagevohgrf gb jnir sbezngvba)

Answer (score 18):

I think you must be a

> Cloud

I am not alive, but I grow;

> Clouds aren't alive but they grow as they form in the atmosphere.

I don't have lungs, but I need air;

> Clouds are necessarily suspended in the air.

I don't have a mouth, but I need water to live.

> Clouds are formed of water droplets. If the water evaporates, the cloud disappears.

Answer (score 8):

I think this could be:

> Rust, which could be considered to grow in the presence of oxygen (air) and water.

Answer (score 4):

I think you must be

> PU (poly-urethane) foam

I am not alive, but I grow;

> growing is the purpose of the PU foam

I don't have lungs, but I need air;

> while growing, PU foam becomes spongy(ier)

I don't have a mouth, but I need water to live.

> PU foam does not expand without water (humidity)

Answer (score 3):

You are a

> underwater bubble

I am not alive, but I grow;

> Bubbles are not alive, but as they rise from deeper water they get bigger

I don't have lungs, but I need air;

> The bubble is filled with air

I don't have a mouth, but I need water to live.

> Underwater bubbles are under water ;-)